# Hiding font awsome icon on full screen desktop

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to hide a telephone icon I've added when the browser is full screen desktop mode.  I am using the template which is online here:  https://sartre.thememountain.com/index-architecture-2.html

So far in mobile mode it looks ok.  When I expand to full screen, the icon is floating in the corner.  I want to hide fa-phone from view.

```
            <header class="header header-fixed header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-bkg-threshold="100">
                <div class="header-inner">
                    <div class="row nav-bar">
                        <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                            
                            <div class="logo">
                                <div class="logo-inner">
                                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/architecture/logo-dark.png" alt="Happy Kids Logo" /></a>
                                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/architecture/logo-dark.png" alt="Happy Kids Logo" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                                <ul>
```

```
.fa-phone  {

color:#000;
font-size:25px;
display:inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 78%;
top:29%;
    

}
    
.fa-phone:fullscreen{
display: none
}
'''
```

Comment: What `.fa-phone:fullscreen` should do? :-) Check out media queries.

Comment: `.fa-phone { display: none; }`

Comment: Have you used any media queries? How are you going to hide the icon in full screen?

Comment: :fullscreen doesn't feature anywhere else in the code so it's not going to work?  I used this from another post.

Comment: Sergey, thanks.  I used .fa-phone { display: none; } It is hidden on a small window but not on full desktop.

Comment: Pavel thanks, I cracked it.                                                                @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.fa-phone{ display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { /* For desktop: */ .fa-phone{ display: none; }
```